# How to get the sum of a result from a query in SQL

Tags: sql, sum

Using SQL Server 2008, I have two tables: `SALESORD_HDR` and `SALESORD_LINES`

The common identifier is `SALESORD_HDR.SEQNO`

I want to find the sum of the result from this query:

```
Select 
    SOL.STOCKCODE as SC,ORD_QUANT as OQ
from 
    SALESORD_LINES SOL
INNER JOIN 
    SALESORD_HDR SOH ON SOL.HDR_SEQNO = SOH.SEQNO
WHERE 
    SOL.HDR_STATUS = '6' AND SOH.ORDERDATE > DATEDIFF(D,120,getdate())
ORDER BY 
    SOL.STOCKCODE
```

Which gives be the correct data to work with. But I want to find the sum of the values in `ORD_QUANT` for each record of `STOCKCODE`.

I tried putting this:

```
 Select SOL.STOCKCODE as SC,SUM(ORD_QUANT) as OQ
```

but it fails, saying

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'SALESORD_LINES.STOCKCODE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

There will be a way to syntax the SUM that I don't know :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to add a `GROUP BY SOL.STOCKCODE` at the end of your current query (before the `ORDER BY`, though)

Comment: @Lamak add an answer. :)

Comment: @bluefeet I rather vote to close as too localized :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
Select SOL.STOCKCODE as SC,SUM([tableReference].ORD_QUANT) as OQ
from SALESORD_LINES SOL
INNER JOIN SALESORD_HDR SOH
    ON SOL.HDR_SEQNO = SOH.SEQNO
WHERE SOL.HDR_STATUS = '6' AND SOH.ORDERDATE > DATEDIFF(D,120,getdate())
GROUP BY SOL.STOCKCODE 
ORDER BY SOL.STOCKCODE
```

I have also added some pseudo codes `[tableReference]` because you have forgotten to reference which table the fields are from.

Comment: Thanks Phil. I added the references, but now it fails again saying the same error. I added `SOL.ORD_QUANT` in each place. Also, I don't know why @lamak wants to close my question? What is wrong with it? What does 'its too localised' mean when I have asked for help and given all the details I can?

Comment: @Bevan I voted to close because the answer for your question was the line I posted on my comment. You got an answer, but this question is unlikely to help future users. Nothing personal, that's why I posted a comment with the solution for your problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

@Lamak and @Phil Cross have both given good answers. The ammended code is:

```
Select SOL.STOCKCODE as SC,SUM(SOL.ORD_QUANT) as OQ
from SALESORD_LINES SOL
INNER JOIN SALESORD_HDR SOH
ON SOL.HDR_SEQNO = SOH.SEQNO
WHERE SOL.HDR_STATUS = '6' AND SOH.ORDERDATE > DATEDIFF(D,120,getdate())
GROUP BY SOL.STOCKCODE
ORDER BY SOL.STOCKCODE
```

This works. Thankyou all.